# Should I use markdown as a test case format?

Tags: test-design

For anyone who has experience with using markdown to write test cases would you recommend it for test cases?

I am specifically thinking instead of the HPQC step - expected - actual  style, or given-when-then format for test cases?

Answer (score 3):

**So - short answer - YES. I recommend it.**

I use MD in my test-case documentation quite a bit in JIRA, and as you mention, it is especially useful for making test-structure easy to read. I like to use it especially for given-when-then style notation.

An example of how I use it:

```
**given** 
> my test environment has been set up correctly
**and** some other conditions are met

**when** 
> I push _the big red button_

**then** 
> _the big red light_ should flash **and** _the alarm_ should sound
```

results in it being rendered similarly to:

**given**

> my test environment has been set up correctly
>   **and** some other conditions are met

**when**

> I push *the big red button*

**then**

> *the big red light* should flash **and** *the alarm* should sound

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, A test case template in markdown! [Testcases. md](https://gist.github.com/sajeshsf/c7a0d38e7e675c92aa51138dc2a2b59d)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35525)